# Dragging 3-Dimensional Objects with C++ and OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, drag, raycasting

I have been developing a 3d chessboard and I have been stuck trying to drag the pieces for a few days now.

Once I select an object using my ray-caster, I start my dragging function which calculates the difference between the current location of the mouse (in world coordinates) and its previous location, I then translate my object by the difference of these coordinates.

I debug my ray-caster by drawing lines so I am sure those coordinates are accurate.

Translating my object based on the ray-caster coordinates only moves the object a fraction of the distance it should actually go.

Am I missing a step?

-Calvin

I believe my issue is in this line of code....

```
glm::vec3 World_Delta = Current_World_Location - World_Start_Location;
```

If I multiply the equation by 20 the object start to move more like I would expect it to, but it is never completely accurate.

Below is some relevent code

---

**RAY-CASTING:**

```
void CastRay(int mouse_x, int mouse_y) {

int Object_Selected = -1;
float Closest_Object = -1;

//getWorldCoordinates calls glm::unproject
nearPoint = Input_Math.getWorldCoordinates(glm::vec3(mouse_x, Window_Input_Info.getScreenHeight()-mouse_y, 0.0f));
farPoint = Input_Math.getWorldCoordinates(glm::vec3(mouse_x, Window_Input_Info.getScreenHeight()-mouse_y, 1.0f));

glm::vec3 direction = Input_Math.normalize(farPoint - nearPoint);

//getObjectStack() Retrieves all objects in the current scene
std::vector<LoadOBJ> objectList = Object_Input_Info.getObjectStack();
for (int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++) {
    std::vector<glm::vec3> Vertices = objectList[i].getVertices();
    for(int j = 0; j < Vertices.size(); j++) {
        if ( ( j + 1 ) % 3 == 0 ) {
            glm::vec3 face_normal = Input_Math.normalize(Input_Math.CrossProduct(Vertices[j-1] - Vertices[j-2], Vertices[j] - Vertices[j-2]));
            float nDotL = glm::dot(direction, face_normal);
            if (nDotL <= 0.0f ) { //if nDotL == 0 { Perpindicular } else if nDotL < 0 { SameDirection } else { OppositeDirection }
                float distance = glm::dot(face_normal, (Vertices[j-2] - nearPoint)) / nDotL;
                glm::vec3 p = nearPoint + distance * direction;
                glm::vec3 n1 = Input_Math.CrossProduct(Vertices[j-1] - Vertices[j-2], p - Vertices[j-2]);
                glm::vec3 n2 = Input_Math.CrossProduct(Vertices[j] - Vertices[j-1], p - Vertices[j-1]);
                glm::vec3 n3 = Input_Math.CrossProduct(Vertices[j-2] - Vertices[j], p - Vertices[j]);
                if( glm::dot(face_normal, n1) >= 0.0f && glm::dot(face_normal, n2) >= 0.0f && glm::dot(face_normal, n3) >= 0.0f ) {
                    if(p.z > Closest_Object) {

                        //I Create this "dragplane" to be used by my dragging function.
                        Drag_Plane[0] = (glm::vec3(Vertices[j-2].x, Vertices[j-2].y, p.z ));
                        Drag_Plane[1] = (glm::vec3(Vertices[j-1].x, Vertices[j-1].y, p.z ));
                        Drag_Plane[2] = (glm::vec3(Vertices[j].x  , Vertices[j].y  , p.z ));

                        //This is the object the we selected in the scene
                        Object_Selected = i; 

                        //These are the coordinate the ray intersected the object
                        World_Start_Location = p;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
if(Object_Selected >= 0) { //If an object was intersected by the ray
    //selectObject -> Simply sets the boolean "dragging" to true
    selectObject(Object_Selected, mouse_x, mouse_y);
}
```

**DRAGGING**

```
void DragObject(int mouse_x, int mouse_y) {

 if(dragging) {

    //Finds the Coordinates where the ray intersects the "DragPlane" set by original object intersection
    farPoint = Input_Math.getWorldCoordinates(glm::vec3(mouse_x, Window_Input_Info.getScreenHeight()-mouse_y, 1.0f));
    nearPoint = Input_Math.getWorldCoordinates(glm::vec3(mouse_x, Window_Input_Info.getScreenHeight()-mouse_y, 0.0f));
    glm::vec3 direction = Input_Math.normalize(farPoint - nearPoint);
    glm::vec3 face_normal = Input_Math.normalize(Input_Math.CrossProduct(Drag_Plane[1] - Drag_Plane[0], Drag_Plane[2] - Drag_Plane[0]));
    float nDotL = glm::dot(direction, face_normal);
    float distance = glm::dot(face_normal, (Drag_Plane[0] - nearPoint)) / nDotL;
    glm::vec3 Current_World_Location = nearPoint + distance * direction;

    //Calculate the difference between the current mouse location and its previous location
    glm::vec3 World_Delta = Current_World_Location - World_Start_Location;

    //Set the "start location" to the current location for the next loop
    World_Start_Location = Current_World_Location;

    //get the current object
    Object_Input_Info = Object_Input_Info.getObject(currentObject);

    //adds a translation matrix to the stack
    Object_Input_Info.TranslateVertices(World_Delta.x, World_Delta.y, World_Delta.z);

    //calculates the new vertices
    Object_Input_Info.Load_Data();

    //puts the new object back
    Object_Input_Info.Update_Object_Stack(currentObject);

 }
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

I have already faced similar problems to what your reporting.
Instead of keeping track of the translation during mouse movement, you can do the following:
In your mouse button callback, store a 'Delta' vector from the mouse position (in world coordinates) (P_mouse) to your object position (P_object). It would be something like:

```
Delta = P_object - P_mouse;
```

For every call of your mouse motion callback, you just need to update the object position by:

```
P_object = P_mouse + Delta;
```

Notice that Delta is constant during the whole dragging process.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Using your idea as a new way to approach my problem I determined that the issue was not with the code above, but it was with my "Load_Data()" function.